# Remove duplicate rows from SQL UNION Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have the following union query that I am trying to remove duplicate rows from:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Cat_Name, s.SubCat_DisplayName, st.State, COUNT(a.SubCategory_ID) as SubCount
FROM CT_SubCategory s
INNER JOIN CT_Category c ON s.Cat_ID=c.Cat_ID
INNER JOIN CT_AdvertiserSubcategory a ON s.Subcat_ID = a.SubCategory_ID
INNER JOIN CT_AdvertiserCity ac ON ac.UserID = a.UserID
INNER JOIN CT_City ci ON ci.City_ID = ac.City_ID
INNER JOIN CT_State st ON ci.State_ID = st.State_ID
WHERE ci.CityName LIKE 'Grand-Rapids' AND st.Abbr = 'MI'
GROUP BY c.Cat_Name, s.SubCat_Name, s.SubCat_DisplayName, st.State
UNION
SELECT c.Cat_Name, s.SubCat_Name, s.SubCat_DisplayName, null, null
FROM CT_SubCategory s
INNER JOIN CT_Category C ON s.Cat_ID = c.Cat_ID
ORDER BY SubCat_DisplayName
```

Current Results:

```
Auto, Auto Repair, null, null
Auto, Auto Repair, Michigan, 3
Entertainment, Events, null, null
Gifts, Flowers, null, null
```

Desired Results:

```
Auto, Auto Repair, Michigan, 3
Entertainment, Events, null, null
Gifts, Flowers, null, null
```

I'd like to remove the duplicate Auto Repair row with the nulls from my result set.

Is this possible to do with a union query?

Comment: you'll have to dedup after the union statement, but if you want to remove rows with NULL values, you do that in your WHERE clause

Comment: you have to show the expected result in compare with the current result you are getting which you have shown above, your expect result is not clear for us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I understood the question, you don't need `UNION` at all you have to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Cat_Name, s.SubCat_DisplayName, st.State, COUNT(a.SubCategory_ID) as SubCount
FROM CT_SubCategory s
INNER JOIN CT_Category c ON s.Cat_ID=c.Cat_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CT_AdvertiserSubcategory a ON s.Subcat_ID = a.SubCategory_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CT_AdvertiserCity ac ON ac.UserID = a.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CT_City ci ON ci.City_ID = ac.City_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CT_State st ON ci.State_ID = st.State_ID
WHERE ISNULL(ci.CityName,'Grand-Rapids') LIKE 'Grand-Rapids' AND ISNULL(st.Abbr,'MI') = 'MI'
GROUP BY c.Cat_Name, s.SubCat_Name, s.SubCat_DisplayName, st.State
```

and the result should be like this:

```
Auto, Auto Repair, Michigan, 3
Entertainment, Events, null, null
Gifts, Flowers, null, null
```

Comment: Your `where` clause undoes the `left join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, answer edited, also you can put the where clause outside of the query(make as subquery)

Comment: `AND st.Abbr = 'MI'` still undoes the outer join of st. It has to be in the join condition.

Comment: @Sebas answer edited, but I think the best way in this case is to bring the the where clause outside the query like `select * from (select tbla.a as a, tblb.b as b from tbla left outer join tblb on tbla.id=tblb.id) where b='some value'`

Comment: also I think `the idea of using left join` is important not the detail of query which the question owner can manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

Farhang's answer is ok.  But the right way to write the query is to put the `where` condition in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Cat_Name, s.SubCat_DisplayName, st.State,
       COUNT(a.SubCategory_ID) as SubCount
FROM CT_SubCategory s INNER JOIN
     CT_Category c
     ON s.Cat_ID = c.Cat_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CT_AdvertiserSubcategory a
     ON s.Subcat_ID = a.SubCategory_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CT_AdvertiserCity ac
     ON ac.UserID = a.UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CT_City ci
     ON ci.City_ID = ac.City_ID AND
        ci.CityName = 'Grand-Rapids' LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CT_State st
     ON ci.State_ID = st.State_ID AND
        st.Abbr = 'MI'
GROUP BY c.Cat_Name, s.SubCat_Name, s.SubCat_DisplayName, st.State;
```

`ISNULL()` (or as I prefer `COALESCE()`) returns unexpected results if `CityName` or `Abbr` is ever `NULL` in the data.  For filtering on the right-hand table in a `left join`, you should put the conditions in the `on` clause.

Comment: Great answer. I'm using a built in Kentico CMS control so I need to have the where condition as a full statement for it to work with Kentico